# How to create factory that dynamically creates values and returns borrows to them?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrow

I'd like to have a `struct` called Factory that dynamically produces new `Strings`, keeps them inside itself and returns `&str` borrows of them that live as long as the Factory value itself.

I tried to keep new values inside in a `Vec` but as `Vec` grows borrows to elements would get invalidated so they don't live long enough. I tried wrapping them in `Boxes`, `RefCells` but I encounter same problems.

I would also like to call this factory method inside a loop so I can make new String in each iteration and get a borrow of it to keep somewhere.

---

There's a crate called string-interner: https://docs.rs/string-interner/latest/string_interner/index.html

It might be a good idea to use it either directly or through similar structs as below if what you are after are just String handles.

---

That's what I've got so far thanks to your comments:

```
use std::{ cell::{Ref, RefCell}, rc::Rc, }; 

struct StringHandle {
    key: usize,
    store: Rc<RefCell<Vec<String>>>,
}
impl StringHandle {
    pub fn get(&self) -> Ref<String> {
        Ref::map(self.store.borrow(), |v| &v[self.key])
    }
}

struct Factory {
    pub store: Rc<RefCell<Vec<String>>>,
}
impl Factory {
    pub fn make_next_string(&mut self) -> StringHandle {
        let len = self.store.borrow().len();
        self.store.borrow_mut().push(format!("string no. {}", len));
        StringHandle {
            store: self.store.clone(),
            key: len,
        }
    }
    pub fn new() -> Factory {
        Factory { store: Rc::new(RefCell::new(vec![])) }
    }
}

let mut f = Factory::new();
let mut strs: Vec<StringHandle> = vec![];

for _ in 0..5 {
    let handle = f.make_next_string();
    strs.push(handle);
}

for handle in strs {
    println!("{}", handle.get());
}
```

---

And generic version for structs other than String:

```
use std::{ cell::{Ref, RefCell, RefMut}, rc::Rc, }; 

struct Handle<T> {
    key: usize,
    store: Rc<RefCell<Vec<T>>>,
}
impl<T> Handle<T> {
    pub fn get(&self) -> Ref<T> {
        Ref::map(self.store.borrow(), |v| &v[self.key])
    }
    pub fn get_mut(&self) -> RefMut<T> {
        RefMut::map(self.store.borrow_mut(), |v| &mut v[self.key])
    }
}

struct Factory<T> {
    pub store: Rc<RefCell<Vec<T>>>,
}
impl<T: Default> Factory<T> {
    pub fn make_next(&mut self) -> Handle<T> {
        let len = self.store.borrow().len();
        self.store.borrow_mut().push(T::default());
        Handle {
            store: self.store.clone(),
            key: len,
        }
    }
    pub fn new() -> Factory<T> {
        Factory { store: Rc::new(RefCell::new(vec![])) }
    }

}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data {
    pub number: i32
}

impl Default for Data {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Data { number: 0 }
    }
}

let mut objs: Vec<Handle<Data>> = vec![];
let mut f: Factory<Data> = Factory::new();



for i in 0..5 {
    let handle = f.make_next();

    handle.get_mut().number = i;

    objs.push(handle);
}

for handle in objs {
    println!("{:?}", handle.get());
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a string interner?

Comment: You could use something like [`pinus`](https://crates.io/crates/pinus)

Comment: @PitaJ I don't think so. String is just example. Ultimately I'd like to be able to produce and keep any kind of heap allocated data and get borrows of those that live as long as the "container".

Comment: @PitaJ But that's an interesting idea if I can't do what I'm asking for. Just make stuff, put it in a Vec and pass around index into the vec instead of borrow.

Comment: Using integers (or some key type, depending on what the backing storage is) instead of references definitely sounds like the right way to go.

Comment: @BallpointBen Ok. I think that's a good idea. And I can wrap the factory in `Rc<RefCell<_>>` so I can call it it's `make_stuff(&mut self)` method through `.borrow_mut()` without problem of not being allowed to have multiple mutable references to it at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you have a `&mut` access to the interner, you don't need `RefCell` on it. But you likely want to access it through shared references so you do need.

Another way is to return a newtyped index into the `Vec` instead of references. This saves the indirection, but requires an access to the interner to access the interned string, so it may not fulfill the requirements. This also does not allow you to allocate new strings while you keep references to the old around (using `RefCell` will not help, it will just panic):

```rust
use std::ops::Index;

struct StringHandle(usize);

struct Factory {
    pub store: Vec<String>,
}
impl Factory {
    pub fn make_next_string(&mut self) -> StringHandle {
        let len = self.store.len();
        self.store.push(format!("string no. {}", len));
        StringHandle(len)
    }
    pub fn new() -> Factory {
        Factory { store: vec![] }
    }
}

impl Index<StringHandle> for Factory {
    type Output = str;
    fn index(&self, index: StringHandle) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.store[index.0]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = Factory::new();
    let mut strs: Vec<StringHandle> = vec![];

    for _ in 0..5 {
        let handle = f.make_next_string();
        strs.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in strs {
        println!("{}", &f[handle]);
    }
}
```

The best way is to use an [arena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arena_allocation). It allows you to yield references (and therefore does not require access to the interner to access interned strings), and keep the old around while making new. The disadvantages are that it requires using a crate, as you probably don't want to implement the arena yourself (this also requires unsafe code), and that you can't store that interner alongside the interned strings (this is a self-referential struct). You can use the [`typed-arena`](https://docs.rs/typed-arena) crate for that:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

use typed_arena::Arena;

struct Factory {
    store: Arena<String>,
    len: Cell<u32>,
}

impl Factory {
    pub fn make_next_string(&self) -> &str {
        let len = self.len.get();
        self.len.set(len + 1);
        self.store.alloc(format!("string no. {}", len))
    }
    pub fn new() -> Factory {
        Factory { store: Arena::new(), len: Cell::new(0) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Factory::new();
    let mut strs: Vec<&str> = vec![];

    for _ in 0..5 {
        let interned = f.make_next_string();
        strs.push(interned);
    }

    for interned in strs {
        println!("{}", interned);
    }
}
```

You can also store `str`s inside the arean (instead of `String`s) The advantages are better cache access as the structure is more flat and much faster drop of the interner itself due to not needing to loop over and drop the stored strings; the disadvantage is that you need to copy the strings before you store them. I recommend [`bumpalo`](https://docs.rs/bumpalo):

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

use bumpalo::Bump;

struct Factory {
    store: Bump,
    len: Cell<u32>,
}

impl Factory {
    pub fn make_next_string(&self) -> &str {
        let len = self.len.get();
        self.len.set(len + 1);
        self.store.alloc_str(&format!("string no. {}", len))
    }
    pub fn new() -> Factory {
        Factory { store: Bump::new(), len: Cell::new(0) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Factory::new();
    let mut strs: Vec<&str> = vec![];

    for _ in 0..5 {
        let interned = f.make_next_string();
        strs.push(interned);
    }

    for interned in strs {
        println!("{}", interned);
    }
}
```